# «[…] confirmed what observed»: is this correct English?

Tags: grammar

> The measurement of the cell yield in liquid cultures confirmed what observed in the spot assay analysis (Fig. 3C).

I bumped into this sentence today, and that «what observed» feels like it's missing a *was*, i.e. it should be «what **was** observed». I could even explain it as an italianism, seen as the sentence would translate to «[…] hanno confermato quanto osservato […]», where *quanto* is a relative pronoun and hence translates to *what*, and *osservato* is the past participle of osservare=observe, hence translates to *observed*, stitch the two together et voilà, «what observed». I am not a native and have no detailed grammatical rule to support this claim though, which is why I am asking:

> Is this acceptable or is it ungrammatical, as my gut feeling suggests? Could you pinpoint why it is ungrammatical, if it is?

Comment: You are right. It should be 'what **was** observed.'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"...confirmed what was observed in the spot assay analysis." puts the relative clause in passive voice, meaning that the measurement confirmed the observations in the spot analysis.

"...confirmed what observed in the spot assay analysis." puts the relative clause in active voice, meaning that the measurement confirmed what was doing the observing in the spot assay analysis.

Context strongly suggests that the former is the meaning you're looking for, in which case "what was observed" is correct.